# Identifying a chasid

Tags: derech-eretz-manners, chasidut-hasidism, words

Say you meet a stranger who is a member of a particular community of *chasidus*. What is the most polite and direct way to ask the person of which community they are a member? I.e. a question whose answer could be one word, such as "Munkatcher", "Gerer", or "Toldos Aharon". "What are you?" is obviously impolite and imprecise. "What kind of *chasid* are you?" seems only slightly less so. "Where are you from?" just doesn't express the intended question.

This is a question of social graces and terminology, not one of taxonomy.

Comment: I recently asked someone "What _chasidus_ are you a _chasid_ of", but definitely sounded awkward to my own ears.

Comment: If you are a real levush maven, you don't have to ask

Comment: @DesertStar Clearly, [I am not](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4165/3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Who is your Rebbe?
- Which chasidus are you?
- Where do you daven?

Comment: Where do you daven is probably best, you can take it further from there.

Answer (score 4):

"Where do you belong?"

Observed in an overheard conversation between two *chasidim*.

The reply was, "[NAME OF *CHASIDUS*] but I daven at Ger."

Answer (score 2):

Vi Dreist Zi Zich?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Something like "where do you hang out."

Comment: That has a Negative connotation

Comment: Why does it have a negative connotation?

Comment: Because you Drei a Kup

Comment: The answer was appropriate to the question.

Comment: Literally it means "Where do you play yourself?"

Comment: More to spin then play thats why it is called a Dreidle