# Rabbis who don't wear neck ties?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, clothing

I have noticed many Haredi Rabbonim who do not wear ties through out the year (Shabbos, Yom Tov, Simchas) even though they aren't chasidish.

Does anyone know the reason?

I was thinking along the lines due to the historical association with of ties.

"There is a long history of neckwear worn by soldiers (Roman), whether as part of a uniform or as a symbol of belonging to a particular group. Some form of neckwear other than the outdoor scarf can be traced intermittently through many centuries." (Wikipedia)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would expect them TO wear neckties?

Comment: Halachicly: No.......Social Conformity: Yes

Comment: This is basically answered by this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11784/440

Comment: @Yishaq Conformity with whom? The question intimates that there is something about being a Rabbi which demands a tie (the question doesn't ask about Chareidim in general) and which separates Chareidim from other groups in terms of tie wearing. So with whom must Chareidim conform?

Comment: @danno the question intimates that there are many Rabbonim who wear ties. That's it. Don't go so crazy on diyukim here.

Comment: @Yishaq the question asks about "[C}haredi Rabbonim." Not Chareidim in general, and yet there is an expectation of ties. So the expectation must be among rabbis, but the question includes "Chareidim" so the lack of a tie on a MO rabbi is expected and not to be questioned. So whom are the Charei Rabbonim conforming with? Why isn't the question asked in reverse -- some do wear ties! Why don't they doff them to conform?

Comment: @danno You lost me. I'm dealing with Haredi rabbis. No need to bring in MO rabbis.

Comment: @yishaq exactly -- what does this have to do with Chareidi Rabbis in particular that it doesn't apply to other rabbis who don't wear ties? To what should the Chareidi rabbis conforming that others don't have to?

Comment: @danno Chareidim conform to many styles that MO rabbis don't.

Comment: @yishaq OK, then my initial question stands -- to what standard is there an expectation that Chareidi Rabbis conform and who set that expectation?

Comment: Is this a question about Jews or Judaism?

Answer (score 2):

A necktie is a vestige of Western culture and is not a historically Jewish garment that was worn centuries ago except among Jewish communities influenced by their non-Jewish environment. For example, Jews of German ancestry are often referred to by others as "Yekkes" [because of their shorter jackets than those worn by Polish and Lithuanian Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yekke#Etymology).

Haredi rabbis likely have little interest in wearing clothing that connote an affection and association with popular Western culture and are more inclined to wear clothing associated with rabbinical authorities including frocks and possibly [Homburgs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homburg_%28hat%29) (i.e. "up hats")

(Although *all* clothing is influenced by the environment in which one lives, and frocks and Homburg were worn by non-Jews at some point in the past, nevertheless these garments are not *associated* with non-Jewish clothing anymore.)

See [this similar question and answers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/do-chasidim-avoid-wearing-ties).

Comment: The only heter to wear Homburgs is that they aren't worn by non-Jews _anymore_? Are you implying Jews only started wearing them after the non-Jews stopped??

Comment: @DoubleAA No only that they are not *associated* (by the groups that wears them) with nonJews anymore, as I wrote.

Comment: Are you implying Jews only started wearing them after they stopped being associated with non-Jews?????

Comment: @DoubleAA the question has nothing to do with with whether it's mutar to wear a homburg. It's a sociological question.. Why some people don't wear certain clothing like neckties. I'm not either addressing historical dressing habits. The question is about current dressing habits. I think it'd true that today chareidi rabbis would not wear clothing that they currently associate with Western society. You disagree with that a assertion?

Comment: I guess not, as long as you clarify that such a position is not a traditional Jewish one.

Comment: @DoubleAA I font know if it's traditional or not. My guess is that religions Jews did not follow the current trending styles among non Jews in the past. My guess I'd that they likely were not at the cutting edge of style and instead we're behind by a few styles to avoid ubechusaihem but I don't really have any evidence. Do you?

Comment: You do have evidence. That they wore Homburgs.

Comment: @Yoni There's also a difference regarding what's considered dignified clothing. Homburgs, frocks etc. are clothing worn by dignified people. (I think even noble prize winners today wear frocks, but I'm not sure.) Rabbis always wore dignified clothing of their time (think sefardi chachamim wearing turbans etc.) Especially this past century, when people stopped dressing as "formally" there's been a change. (JFK was first US president not to wear a hat. People stopped wearing sport coats out in public. Chareidim have kept more of the old-time "dignified" clothing modes of dress.

Answer (score 1):

A possible rationale was provided by [R. Aaron Rakeffet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff) in a lecture:

> So I have to tell you Aryeh that Aaron Rakeffet danced for joy when he found out that it's the third topic on which I'm in total agreement with the Eidah Chareidit. Number one: they don't wear ties. I agree with them wholeheartedly. Tie is the only article of clothing you wear to be a *ba'al ga'aveh*. It serves no purpose. At least a belt holds up your pants. What does a tie do? It chokes you.
>
> (My transcription)