# Kashrus status of menurkeys

Tags: halacha, menora-chanukia, non-jewish-holidays

Sorry for the [groan-worthy play on words](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22315/5) (ok, no I'm not), but what is the Halachic, usability status of [this product](http://menurkey.com/):

[image: Hanukah menorah in the form of a turkey sculpture, with the candle-holders arrayed in an arc behind the tips of the turkey's feathers.]

[Another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31549/5) asks about ritualistic problems or concerns with deliberately mixing the holidays of Hanukah and Thanksgiving in [a year when they coincide](http://jonathanmizrahi.blogspot.com/2013/01/hanukkah-and-thanksgiving-once-in.html) on the calendar.

That's one concern. Another concern might be the design of the thing. That is, most people typically understand that the lights need to be fairly level while burning.  A mitigating factor could be that you use candles of different heights or use some sort of base to raise the bottoms of the candles set on the lower pedestals.  But an interesting point [raised here](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/591946/jewish/What-is-a-kosher-Menorah.htm) is that

> The eight candles of the menorah must be arranged in a straight line, not set in a semicircle. Similarly, the menorah’s lights should be level ***or on an even slant, not some randomly higher than others***.
>   (Emphasis mine)

So that should solve that issue.  I've also seen [many](http://bydianedaniel.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/200910_32b_sue-treuman_womanorah.jpg) [examples](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2507/4058862148_6fd1009475_o.jpg) of [sculpted](http://www.lemontreetales.com/.shared/image.html?/photos/uncategorized/menorah_2nd_night.jpg) [Hanukiyoth](http://bydianedaniel.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/200910_31_sue-treuman_menorah.jpg) that could pose a problem of [making a Berachah in front of an image/statue](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28394/5), so if I were afraid of that, <s>I'm sure</s> I assume someone would have raised that issue by now and these wouldn't be on the market.

**Are these issues (probably) ok, and could there be any other (seemingly) problematic issues with this (whether or not they actually turn out to be fine)?**

Comment: hiddur mitzvah?

Comment: Note that their Kickstarter model has the candles on one level: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/ksr/assets/000/817/891/3f9bd7184be8e7679703ce38ed0a1d57_large.png?1376090683

Comment: Why so many candle spots? Thanksgiving is the second night of chanukkah. Do they paskin like Beit Shamai?

Comment: While it is true that the candles all have to be on the same level, classic halacha allows them to be in a semi-circle or even a full circle. (The Gemara in Shabbat 23b allows it - as does the Rambam Hil. Chauka Ch. 4 מִלֵּא קְעָרָה שֶׁמֶן וְהִקִּיפָהּ פְּתִילוֹת. אִם כָּפָה עָלֶיהָ כְּלִי כָּל פְּתִילָה וּפְתִילָה נֶחְשֶׁבֶת כְּנֵר אֶחָד  and Shulchan Aruch O.C. 671)