# Notable Rabbanim and Thanksgiving

Tags: rabbis, non-jewish-holidays, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik, thanksgiving

I know (from a friend who attends) that the Maimonides, the school founded by R' Soloveitchik, observes Thanksgiving. Did the Rav, or any other notable American Rabbanim, observe Thanksgiving?

Comment: **Turkeys**
Some rabbis won't eat turkey, because it wasn't mentioned in the torah as a kosher bird. The others say that since turkeys aren't birds of prey, they are okay to eat. **Thanksgiving in general**
One of my rabbi's told me that: we should give thanks to g-d everyday. Everyday for jews is thanksgiving.

Answer (score 2):

I heard from Rabbi Aharon  rakkeffet that rav yoshe ber did celebrate  thanksgiving. He also mentions this in an interview:

You have an interesting story about Rav Soloveitchik concerning Thanksgiving. Can you share it?

The Rav used to come in from Boston Tuesday morning, said shiur at 1:00 in the afternoon, and then again at 10:00 Wednesday morning. One year he couldn’t come in Tuesday because of a wedding in Boston, so he came in Wednesday. After he finished shiur on Wednesday, he looked at his watch and said, “Tomorrow, we’ll say the shiur at 9:00, will you be here?” I said, “Rebbe, we’ll be there, but why so early?”

So the Rav looked at me: “Arnold, don’t you understand? Tomorrow’s Thanksgiving. We have Thanksgiving dinner with my sister, and I promised my wife we’ll be there at 2:00. So I have to catch the 12:00 plane.”

I had never celebrated Thanksgiving. I was a kana’i like most kids. When I came home and told my mother the story, she was in ecstasy. She said to me, “Why can’t you be modern like Rav Soloveitchik?

http://matzav.com/from-lakewood-to-yeshiva-university

Comment: R. Rakeffet has told this story numerous times in his lectures over the years. Most recently he repeated it last week: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/894144/rabbi-dr-aaron-rakeffet-rothkoff/rabbi-joseph-b-soloveitchik-part-5/                       
around 40 minutes into the lecture.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31549/celebrating-thanksgiving-and-hanukkah-together/31551#31551), the Rav did celebrate Thanksgiving.

> Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik was noted as moving his lecture earlier on Thanksgiving morning so he could catch the plane back to Boston for Thanksgiving dinner at his sister's house.

[Is one allowed to have a Thanksgiving Meal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/thanksgiving-meal-allowed) is also relevant. From Alex's answer there:

> In a nutshell: R' Moshe Feinstein and R' J.B. Soloveitchik seem to have little or no problem with such a meal, while R' Yitzchak Hutner (all three zt"l) argues that it is prohibited as a gentile custom.

Comment: I believe Rav Moshe actually only allowed it if it is not observed religiously - i.e. only on a casual/informal basis.