# Kosher shops selling turkeys

Tags: kashrut-kosher, transactions, business, non-jewish-holidays, poultry

I have noticed a Kosher shop selling turkeys only at this time of the year (...late December). Without getting into a discussion about the [Kashrut status of turkeys](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22315/kashrus-status-of-turkeys), is this considered in the spirit of a Kosher shop to sell such an item and, could it be considered (at worst) 'chukat hagoi'?

Comment: What in the world is a "spirit of a Kosher shop"??

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4120/759

Comment: @double aa, relevant, surely, but I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: I thought the stereotype was that Christians tend to eat a large ham on their holiday. Maybe they're catering to Jews who like turkey and missed Thanksgiving. Maybe they're leftover frozen turkeys that other stores couldn't sell for Thanksgiving, and which this store bought at a discount.  Did you ask the store management why you don't see turkeys the rest of the year?

Comment: @SethJ, i didn't ask the manager, but this is in the UK.

Comment: They raise turkeys in the UK?

Comment: of course, i would imagine that some slipped their way into the shechita houses!