# What rabbi recommended that American Jews skip Tachanun on Thanksgiving?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tachanun, non-jewish-holidays, thanksgiving

A friend of mine told me about a Conservative rabbi from JTS who recommended that American Jews not say Tachanun on Thanksgiving. Who was this rabbi, and is there a link to the text of this opinion so we can understand his reasoning? Additionally, are there any Orthodox rabbis that hold by a similar opinion?

Comment: I haven't tracked this down, but have at it -- http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/272941/thanksgiving-and-halacha.html comment 10, "Shearith Israel, the original synagogue in New York, celebrated the 1789 Thanksgiving Day described in the article with a special service including some of the Hallel tehillim and no Tachanun. It still follows this nusach for Thanksgiving to this day."

Comment: Related "Here is the 1945 Minhat Todah- Service for Thanksgiving Day, Congregation Shearith Israel, NY by Rabbi David de Sola Pool."  https://kavvanah.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/service-for-thanksgiving-day-1945-rabbi-david-de-sola-pool/

Comment: @Danno, [I've been there](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6215/5), and I can confirm that they do.

Comment: @Danno, to be perfectly honest, I'd forgotten whether they skipped Tahanun. Even though they recite some Perakim of Hallel, that is done toward the end. I was unsure how far they take the concept. I emailed them this week, and this is the reply I received: "We say no tahanun on Thanksgiving. Tahanun would be inconsistent with the spirit of Hallel and hodaah and with our actually adopting the day as a kind of holiday."

Comment: I believe most of us skipped it this year!

Comment: @JoshK And we even said Hallel! #PTIJ - reminds me of that question about St. Patrick’s Day falling out on Moshe Rabbeinu’s yahrtzeit.

Answer (score 4):

The Spanish-Portuguese Synagogue ([Cong. Shearith Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congregation_Shearith_Israel)) omits "*tahanunim*" and recites special psalms. The current rabbi is [Meir Soloveichik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Soloveichik). [Source](http://shearithisrael.org/content/thanksgiving-service-and-rabbis-lecture).